# Primefaces orderlist with column headers

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to create a p:orderlist with column headers? I have tried to code it like a dataTable with columnGroups,rows, columns but this didn't render.

In my orderList I want to display 6 columns of data and would like the user to see one header for each column?

Answer (score 4):

This might not be perfect, but it's how I managed to display some headers for an `orderList`. You just need to adjust the `css` rules, to have the header for example aligned left and whatever you want.

```
<p:orderList styleClass="your-orderlist" value="#{controller.fields}" var="field"
iconOnly="true" effect="clip" itemValue="#{field}" converter="#{fieldConverter}">
    <f:facet name="caption">
        <div class="your-orderlist-header" style="width: 33%;">Field Name</div>
        <div class="your-orderlist-header" style="width: 33%;">Value</div>
        <div class="your-orderlist-header" style="width: 33%;">Type</div>
    <div style="clear: both;" />
    </f:facet>

   <p:column styleClass="your-orderlist-row" style="width:33%;">
       <h:outputText value="#{field.fieldName}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column styleClass="your-orderlist-row" style="width:33%;">
       <h:outputText value="#{field.value}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column styleClass="your-orderlist-row" style="width:33%;">
       <h:outputText value="#{field.type}" />
   </p:column>
</p:orderList>
```